# In multivariate error function: why $\frac{1}{2n}$ in $E(w)=\frac{1}{2n} \|Xw -t \|_2^2$?

Tags: expected-value, multivariate-normal-distribution

In multivariate error function: why $\frac{1}{2n}$ in $E(w)=\frac{1}{2n} \|Xw -t \|_2^2$?

What does it do? What is it related to?

Comment: Convenience: the $\frac{1}{n}$ makes this an average over the elements while the $\frac12$ disappears when you take the derivative of a squared term

Answer (score 4):

The $\frac{1}{n}$-term is crucial for asymptotic considerations, since under the usual assumptions one has $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \mathbb{E}(X_i) + O_p(n^{-1/2}),$$
i.e. you are trying to approximate an expected value by writing $\frac{1}{n}||Xw-t||_2^2$ instead of just $||Xw-t||_2^2$.
The $\frac{1}{2}$-factor on the other hand simplifies some derivations. for instance, the first derivative of $\frac{1}{2}||Xw-t||_2^2$ with respect to $w$ simplifies in comparison to just differencing $||Xw-t||_2^2$ with respect to $w$.